# Moving form made of PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have form made of a PictureBox that goes from one edge to another. I have FormBorderStyle set to None. But when I run my app I can't move it anywhere.

Is there any code that would help me solve this problem? I've tried WndProc but didn't work for me.

Comment: What does "didn't work for me" mean

Comment: well i googled it and someone said that WndProc shoud solve the problem but it didn't

Comment: Controls (with the exception being Forms) can only be moved around at design time. If you need to be able to move them at runtime, you'll need to implement this functionality

Answer (score 0):

Catch the MouseMove, MouseDown and MouseUp events of your form. In the MouseDown event, store the relative mouse position and set a flag, move the form using the previously stored position and reset the flag.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do this with a little bit of pinvoke:

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
                                     int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  pictureBox1.MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown;
}

void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  ReleaseCapture();
  SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
}
```